# Saving multiple .mat files from workspace to .txt files

Tags: matlab

I have created a script to create ~300 variable names in my workspace. I need to save these .mat files to .txt files - is there any way to call these variables in some sort of loop or just save them all at once to .txt files?

They are all cells of varying size, about 1000x5 on average.
The first row of the data contains strings, the other elements are all non integer numbers.

Here is an example of one of the .mat files-

http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=1065782

I don't know a whole lot about Matlab so any help would be really appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You need to clarify what you need with these .txt files. Do they have to interop with another program? Should they be in a specific format? Are you going to read it back into Matlab in the future?

Comment: Sorry about that lack of clarification! I need the .txt file to import into Mathematica as a table with the same dimensions as the .mat file

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be:

to load the `.mat`files through a loop (the name of the file can be either dynamically generated or read from a list)

to extract the first row of the cellarray (the string) and write it in a `.txt` file by using the `dlmwrite` function

to remove the first row and write (again with `dlmwrite`) the numerical values in the `.txt` having converted them using the `cell2mat` function.In the writing of the numerical values, the `precision` has to carefully set.

```
file_name_root='x2413';
% dummy loop (one iteration) just to test dynamic filename generation
for i=3:3
   % generate the name of the input file
   input_file_name=[file_name_root int2str(i)];
   % generate the name of the output file
   output_file_name=[file_name_root int2str(i) '.txt'];
   % extract the name of the cellarray and assign it to "the_cell" variable
   tmp=load(input_file_name);
   var_name=char(fieldnames(tmp));
   eval(['the_cell=tmp.' var_name ';'])
   [r,c]=size(the_cell);
   str='';
   % get the first row string (probably a cleaver way to do it exists)
   for i=1:c
      str=[str ' ' char(the_cell(1,i))];
   end
   % print the first row in a ".txt" file
   dlmwrite(output_file_name,sprintf('%s',str),'delimiter','')
   % remove the first row
   the_cell(1,:)=[];
   % write the numerical values in the ".txt" file
   % the "precision" shall be carefully set
   dlmwrite(output_file_name,cell2mat(the_cell),'precision','%13.9f','delimiter',' ','-append')
end
```